# Limit JSON data request

Tags: java, json, spring, tomcat

I have a Rest API build with Spring MVC which has a controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void postTest(@RequestBody FileUpload fileUpload) {
    System.out.println(fileUpload.getFilename());
    System.out.println(fileUpload.getFiletype());
    System.out.println(fileUpload.getFilesize());
}
```

My question is how do I put a size limit on the file being uploaded, so that my server cant be crashed with a upload of 1GB.

Comment: read the filesize in javascript and stop the upload there itself.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to close this hole on the server side, either in spring or tomcat.

Comment: I think this answers your question. See the `Tuning file upload limits` section https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: Yes this does work, but... This only works when the front end is sending a form.

Im using angularjs to serialize the formdata to a json object with a content-type of application/json with the file upload being encoded to base64 and added to the object as a string.

The json object would be sended in the body of the request. I would like the web server to have a limit on how big the body may be.

Comment: Hope this stack overflow link helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943477/is-there-a-max-size-for-post-parameter-content

Answer (score 0):

If I am followig your qustion correction, you could put the file being uploaded into a Model object and check the size:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processUploadWithModelAttribute(@ModelAttribute("myModelAttribute") 
final MyModelAttribute myModelAttribute, final BindingResult result,
 final Model model) throws IOException {        

    // CHECK FOR file.getSize()
}
```

You would need to create the MyModel Object with Multipart file in it.

Similar to [How do I display validation errors about an uploaded multipart file using Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083036/how-do-i-display-validation-errors-about-an-uploaded-multipart-file-using-spring)

Comment: But this would mean that the server first has to receive the complete file and then check for the size. That would make somebody be able to upload a 1GB file to my web server. 

I would like the webserver to cut off the connection as soon as it reads the post size of the request is more than xxMB

Comment: I see. I think you will be able to accomplish that by using http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/. Also there is a similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075287/does-maxpostsize-apply-to-multipart-form-data-file-uploads . Hope this helps.

Comment: I also tried that solution bad it doesn't work well in my situations because im not uploading a MultiPartFile. What im doing is serializing the data sent from the front end in the request body. So it only contains text with the content-type set to application/json.

Comment: I am not sure what web server you are using. However, if Tomcat, there is a maxPostSize in Tomcat configuration? http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html

Comment: yeah im using tomcat and I tried the maxPostSize but It only works for application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data and not for sending the json data with application/json as content-type.